# How to access to the exact value of the vertical space before and after a theorem?

Tags: spacing, amsthm

**Background**

I'm using a theorem style where there is a new line between the title and the statement.

```
\newtheoremstyle{simple}
{}{}
{\normalfont}{}
{\normalfont}{}
{\newline}
{{\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{#2}}
  {\thmnote{\hspace{.4em}\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}}}\smallskip}
```

To effectively prevent page break following the title, I decided to put it inside a transparent `tcolorbox` where one can use the key `breakable` and set `lines before break = 3`. (*The reason that I chose to adopt this complicated method is that those "normal" solutions I've found, like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357645/194994), does not work quite well.*)

I have succeeded in producing such a box and wrapping the environment within it. However, I was not able to reproduce the exact vertical spaces before and after a theorem. My guessed value was `\topsep+\parskip`, which is smaller than the actual value (I also tried e.g. `\thm@preskip` and `\thm@postskip`, but they seem to be `0pt`).

**Is there some way to access to the exact value of these vertical spaces?**

(*The goal is to produce the same result, except for page breaking point, with or without the extra `tcolorbox`.*)

---

**Note: the question actually has little to do with `tcolorbox`. The thing I'm interested is the *exact value* of these two lengths:**

[image]

---

Below is a MWE. You can comment and uncomment the `ExplSyntax` part (which wraps a `tcolorbox` around the environment `theorem`) to see the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{simple}
{}{}
{\normalfont}{}
{\normalfont}{}
{\newline}
{{\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{#2}}
  {\thmnote{\hspace{.4em}\ensuremath{(\text{#3})}}}\smallskip}

\theoremstyle{simple}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\PassOptionsToPackage { many } { tcolorbox }
\RequirePackage { tcolorbox }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \minimclass_box_environment:n
  {
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { env/#1/before } { minimalist }
      {
        \begin { tcolorbox }
          [
            enhanced~jigsaw,
            frame~hidden,
            interior~hidden,
            top = 0pt, bottom = 0pt,
            left = 0pt, right = 0pt,
            boxrule = 0pt, boxsep = 0pt,
            before~skip = \topsep+\parskip,
            after~skip = \topsep+\parskip,
            breakable, lines~before~break=3,
          ]
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { env/#1/after } { minimalist }
      {
        \end { tcolorbox }
      }
  }
\minimclass_box_environment:n { theorem }

\ExplSyntaxOff




\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}
  \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  \blindtext
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: On the top of my head I can't think of any better way than manually measuring/read the source code of tcolorbox.

Comment: (that having said there may be some *easier* way to forbid line break there than tcolorbox e.g. \nopagebreak, which seems extremely overkill here)

Comment: @user202729 Yes, but I failed with `\nopagebreak` -  there are questions on this site about applying `\nopagebreak` in this theorem style, but the result is not quite satisfying. Also, I think the problem is not quite related to `tcolorbox`, the only thing left is to know the correct value of the vertical spaces produced by `amsthm`, and then one needs to insert the right value as parameters to `tcolorbox`.

Comment: „To effectively prevent page break following the title“ – isn't that what `\@afterheading` is for? Also, the `needspace` package comes to mind.

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, I have noted this in the question. About a month ago I tried the `\@afterheading` approach but it didn't work in the testing document (unfortunately I didn't keep it), so I switched to this more complicated method, which at least can be guaranteed to always work.

Comment: Here's an earlier answer that was mainly directed at something else, but it addresses the page break: [Itemizing theorem body](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307199)  This really should be built into `amsthm`, but I'm not optimistic.  I'm not experienced in using `tcolorbox` so can't help with that, and don't have time to test.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think I have misstate the question, as `tcolorbox` is not actually quite related to the real question. I have reformulated my question to emphasis the point, i.e., the value for the vertical spaces before and after a theorem.

Comment: These spaces are set with dimensions defined with "internal" names:
`\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}`
You should be able to find the value of `\topsep`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. Then it is strange, as it was exactly `\topsep` that I have been using, but it seems narrower than the actual value. I must have missed something.

Comment: Maybe tcolorbox makes some additional changes to the value being given to it. This one you probably have to read tcolorbox source code?